# Override soft keyboard layout

Tags: android, android-view, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I want to know if it is possible to change the layout as in the xml file for the keyboard design for the android keyboard in any case. Also if i want to have two keyboards in alternate to the existing android keyboard how should i make the hide and show functions for the same using the `KeyboardView` and `IKeyboardListener`.

Answer (score 0):

On non-rooted device you have to create your own IME.
You can switch between keyboard layouts by [KeyboardView.setKeyboard()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#setKeyboard(android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard)).

BTW, your custom service can inflate any kind of view and you can modify view hierarchy by user actions.